# lftp exclude syntax confusion

Tags: regular-expression, wildcards, lftp

I am confused with the syntax description given for lftp from their website:

```
-x RX,   --exclude=RX              exclude matching files
-X GP,   --exclude-glob=GP         exclude matching files
```

How exactly do I exclude certain files during mirroring ??

```
--exclude filea --exclude fileb --exclude filec
--exclude filea fileb filec
--exclude ./filea ./fileb filec
```

I have also googled it and cannot find any examples of exclude statements ?!

Answer (score 9):

`-x RX` is for matching using a `Regular eXpression`, like in `egrep()`, while `-X GX` is used for `Glob Pattern` matching, which is essentially just normal character matching, apart from *****. So for example:

```
# To exclude .svn directories use:
mirror -e -x ^\.svn/$ /myhome/ /elsewhere

# To exclude all folders starting with a dot:
mirror -e -x /\..+/$ /myhome/ /elsewhere

# To exclude all *.bin AND *.so files:
mirror -e -X *.bin -X *.so /myhome/ /elsewhere
```

As you can see, you'll have to use the -X for each filetype, since you're not able to give a list, afaik.

Answer (score 3):

### Here's my (verified, working) take:

Excluding:

- hidden folders & files (also covers .git)
- the scripts/ - Folder (where I keep my `deploy.sh`)
- various active / dangerous / preparation / superficious files (
  nb: regExp with a pipe | operator make (her: inner, single) quotes necessary)

**deploy.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# switch to script parent dir == project dir
cd "$(dirname $(dirname $0))"

if ! [[ "$PWD" =~ \/myproject$ ]]; then
    echo "you are not in the myproject folder!"
    exit 1
fi

# a (relatively) good place to store your credits (outside repo, ...)
read FTPCREDITS < ~/.ssh/creds/FTPCREDITS

if [ -z "$FTPCREDITS" ]; then
    echo "Could NOT read credits. Exiting."
    exit 2
fi
```

**ok, and finally:**

```
lftp -c "set ftp:list-options -a;                                  \
    open $FTPCREDITS;                                               \
    lcd .;                                                         \
    mirror --reverse --delete --use-cache --verbose --allow-chown  \
    --allow-suid --no-umask --parallel=2                           \
    -x '^\.' -x '^script\/'                                        \
    -x '\.(psd|rev|log|cmd|bat|pif|scr|exe|c?sh|reg|vb?|ws?)$'     \
    ;                                                              \
    close -a;"
```

#### good for testing:

- `--dry-run`  (naturally)
- `./script/deploy.sh | grep Transferring` to see more of the relevant

Comment: What's in `FTPCREDITS`? Maybe explain a bit more what that lftp command does.